# Rails forms label and input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I need to convert these 4 tag into my rails application .I dont have much idea about it so anyone can help me. I have even tried but I don't know whether it is right or not.Last one tag no idea how to do that.

```
<label for="devicename">Device Name</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_id" placeholder="Device Name" value="{{name}}"/><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn-remove btn-default">OK</button><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="userInfo.check"></label>
```

mycode-

```
<%= f.label "Device Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :text,:value=>"{{name}}",:placeholder=>"Device Name",:class=>"form-control", :id=>"name_id" %>
<%= f.submit :submit ,:value=> 'OK',:class=>'btn-remove btn-default' %>
```

Comment: Aniket- Your question is not clear? Can you please clearify it ?

Comment: Your code is almost correct. Study Rails form helper to achieve your objective http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: can you tell me how to do the last one and also my first 3 are correct or they  need any improvements?

Comment: `<%= f.submit 'OK', :class => 'btn-remove btn-default' %>`

Comment: Last one is checkbox but without any name. `<%= f.check_box :field, {:class => "myclass"}, "checked-value", "unchecked-value" %>
`

Comment: but how to use label outside it in checkbox ...

Comment: That's not necessary to cover checkbox, but for showing label before checkbox you can use `<%= f.label :label_name %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label for="devicename">Device Name</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_id" placeholder="Device Name" value="{{name}}"/><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn-remove btn-default">OK</button><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="userInfo.check"></label>

<%= label_tag  "name_id", "Device Name" %>
<%= text_field_tag "name_id", "{{name}}", placeholder: "Device Name", class: "form-control" %>
<%= submit_tag "Ok", class: "btn-remove btn-default" %>
<%= check_box_tag "name" %>
```

You need to be sure about several things:

1. [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) has to be used with a model object ([`form_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) can be used without) (the above code uses the `form_tag` helpers)
2. `form_tag` helpers are just functions -- they take arguments in the same way other methods do; thus you have to make sure you're filling them in correctly to get them to work.

---

**Update**

If you're using `form_for`, you need to use the following:

```
<%= f.label :name_id, "Device Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :name_id, "{{name}}", placeholder: "Device Name", class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.submit "Ok", class: "btn-remove btn-default" %>
<%= f.check_box :check_box %>
```

Comment: Hey but  I am using form_for with the object f. But I am facing problem with the last tag <%= f.check_box :check_box,   'ng-model'=>"userInfo.check" %> it is saying undefined method check_box

Comment: Updated - I think you're getting an error because of `ng-model`

Comment: oh now it worked actually i need to include in my model  attr_accessor field